# expand the bootstrap navbar when clicks a drop-down menu occurs

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Hello I want to know if it was possible to expand the bootstrap navbar when I click on a dropdown menu ? please

before click:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|    THE NAVBAR -               dropdown menu \/ |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

after click:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|    THE NAVBAR -               dropdown menu \/ |
|                                     submenu    |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't think such a feature is available in bootstrap built in, but I'm sure you can build it yourself.

Comment: As @Inkbug said. This is not something that can be done using pre-written bootstrap classes. You would need to apply some Javascript to add the desired class to the navbar after clicking on the menu. It should be relatively straight forward to do.

Comment: Why do you uncheck my answer, I'm not claiming anything, you are free to mark the answer that best suits you is just to know why.

Comment: It's just an error. I do not know very well "stackoverflow". sorry. I wanted to mark both as a possible answer because I like both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpful as an example. It's relatively straight forward once you look into the CSS. There are also libraries like [Yamm!3](https://geedmo.github.io/yamm3/).

```css
.navbar-default {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f00 !important;
  background: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-header a.navbar-brand {
  color: #f00;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
  border-top-color: #f00;
  border-bottom-color: #f00;
}
.menu-large {
  position: static !important;
}
.megamenu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.megamenu> li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.megamenu> li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.megamenu> li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #f00;
  white-space: normal;
}
.megamenu> li ul > li > a:hover,
.megamenu> li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.megamenu.dropdown-header {
  color: #428bca;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.megamenu img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .megamenu {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .megamenu> li {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .megamenu> li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .megamenu.dropdown-header {
    padding: 3px 15px !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown menu-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Stuff <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row ">
            <li>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 ">
                <a href="# " class="img-responsive ">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300/f00/fff" />
                </a>

              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 ">
                <a href="# " class="img-responsive ">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300/f00/fff" />
                </a>

              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 ">
                <a href="# " class="img-responsive ">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300/f00/fff" />
                </a>

              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 ">
                <a href="# " class="img-responsive ">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/300/f00/fff" />
                </a>

              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown menu-large "> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Things <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row ">
            <li class="col-sm-3 ">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header ">Item I Main</li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item I Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li class="disabled "><a href="# ">Item II Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item III Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li class="divider "></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header ">Item II Main</li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item I Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item II Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item III Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item VI Sub</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3 ">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header ">Item III Main</li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item I Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item II Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item III Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item VI Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item V Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li class="divider "></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header ">Item IV Main</li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item I Sub</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3 ">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header ">Item V Main</li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item I Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item II Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item III Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li class="divider "></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header ">Item VI Main</li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item I Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item II Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item III Sub</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-3 ">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header ">Item VII Main</li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item I Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item II Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item III Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item VI Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item V Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item VI Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item VII Sub</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item VIII Subp</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="# ">Item VIIII Sub</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using bootstrap collapse like this:

```css
.my-menu{
  padding: 10px;
}

#collapse-menu{
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default my-nav-bar" role="navigation">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logotipo</a>

        <div class="pull-right my-menu"> 
            <button href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu"> <!--add the atributes data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-menu" to the element that you want to be the collapser-->
                  Dropdown Menu <b class="caret"></b>
            </button>

            <ul id="collapse-menu" class="list-group collapse">  <!--add the class "collapse" to the element that you want collapse-->
                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Acción #1</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Acción #2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
```